# Type or namespace name does not exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, namespaces, kentico

I am using the code below :

```
using CMS.DataEngine;
using CMS.DocumentEngine;

namespace Fort.CMS.CMSPages
{
    public partial class CreatePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        #region "Variables"

        private CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode mNode;
        private TreeProvider mTree;
```

Getting error at the line: private CMS.DocumentEngine.TreeNode mNode;

> Error :
>
> Type or namespace name "DocumentEngine" does not exist in the
>   namespace "Fort.CMS"

Here DocumentEngine is not recognized.

But it works if we remove the namespace.

```
namespace Fort.CMS.CMSPages
{}
```

Comment: Is `CMS.DocumentEngine` a different namespace from another library?

Comment: No, its not but there are conflicts in namespace hence we need to put absolute path of namespace

Comment: Actually, YES `CMS.DocumentEngine` is a namespace in the Kentico library..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is namespace conflict.use as below

```
using CMS.DataEngine;
using DE=CMS.DocumentEngine;

namespace Fort.CMS.CMSPages
{
    public partial class CreatePage : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        #region "Variables"

        private DE.TreeNode mNode;
        private TreeProvider mTree;
```

Comment: Never post only code without an explanation, it doesn't help anyone.